# Build for iOS 10 using frameworks with Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I'm trying to understand what the implications of Swift 5 are.

I want to leave the minSDK on my project at iOS 10, however I plan to use a cocoapod that is build with Swift 5. Will there be a problem with regards to a missing Swift runtime or similar? I am building with the latest Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Xcode 12 ???????

Comment: sorry typo, I meant 10.2.1